# How to get PHP max_execution_time from the command line?

Tags: php

When I run a script in the *browser*, I can *get* the time limit that is set in the configuration with:

```
ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

When I run a script from the *command line*, I can *set* the time limit with:

```
php -d max_execution_time=5 script.php
```

But how can I **get** the maximum execution time in the command line?

Comment: The CLI has the `max_execution_time` set to 0. So there is no execution time limit in the CLI, unless you specifically set it using `ini_set('max_execution_time',5)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

PHP cli by default not have `max_execution_time` limit

You can get by running:

```
php -i | grep max_execution_time
```

Comment: Nice, didn't now about `-i`.

Comment: Does this work for php processes started with option `-d max_execution_time=5` like stated in OPs question?

Comment: I hae php 5.3.3, but it's telling me my max is 0=>0 .  I'm not sure then what my max is?

Answer (score 4):

### PHP>=5.2

```
$ php -r "echo ini_get('max_execution_time') . PHP_EOL;";
```

### PHP<5.2

```
$ echo "<?php echo ini_get('max_execution_time') . PHP_EOL;" | php
```

Comment: `Could not open input file: ini_get("max_execution_time");`

Comment: Sorry. You need `-r`

Comment: `php -r "echo ini_get('max_execution_time');";` returns nothing.

Comment: @what It does, but on my machine it's on the same line as the next prompt.

Comment: Ah, yes, at the beginning. Strange. But works. Thank you.

Comment: @what Added `PHP_EOL` so it adds an extra line.